# Sitecore Visio Stencils

Tags: solution-architecture

I've seen a few diagrams on the Sitecore developer sites and but does anyone know if they are distributing the stencils somewhere?  I'd like to capture the infrastructure topology at our client.

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you are referring to?

Comment: No, unfortunately they do not.

Comment: If you reach out to Martina Welander (@mhwelander on Sitecore Slack) then she may be able to help point you in the right direction. I've mostly just been making my own stencils though. You take a server stencil, add the Sitecore logo and save it as a new stencil and *presto*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't heard anything about Vision Stencils for Sitecore. But on an architecture visualization perspective I would recommend you to try Sitecore UML Tool. Its an architecture visualization tool helps visualize existing Sitecore architectures in UML and to create, visualize and deploy new Sitecore template architectures directly from their UML diagrams. It even has the power to generate MSDN-style documentation for any Sitecore architecture.

https://github.com/zkniebel/SitecoreUML